# Blazor .NET 8 - Staging launch profile not starting website VS2022

Tags: c#, blazor, visual-studio-2022, iis-express, .net-8.0

I have a Blazor .NET 8 application and I am trying to have it run in Staging in VS2022 in order to apply config transforms:

[image]

Setting launch profile as follows:

[image: launch profile https]

[image: launch profile IIS]

When I run my application I can see it is now hitting the breakpoint in Program.cs as expected:

[image: Program.cs]

Beyond this a browser window opens which is stuck on about:blank for a minute or so, then I eventually get this error back:

[image]

I have tested VS2022 with Blazor .NET 7 and MVC .NET 8 and launch profiles work as expected with no error, so this issue is specific to Blazor .NET 8. I tried creating a fresh Blazor .NET 8 app to see if it was the .sln I am working on is the issue, but it is also apparent with a new project.

Also worth mentioning I had one of my colleagues follow these steps and he was able to recreate the issue.

Has anybody come across this before and is it a bug that needs raising with Microsoft VS2022?

Thanks in advance

Rob

Comment: How do you run the app? With debugger attached? Have you tried launching it without debugger (CNTRL + F5/ Start without debugging from the menu)?

Comment: Yes with the debugger attached. I just ran without debugger attached and it did fire up the site at https://localhost:7142/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a Blazor expert but the culprit seems to be the debugging. Since you run app in staging environment the `app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging()` is not called which seems to break VS when you are running in the debug. As workaround you can:

- Run without debugging (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> for example)
- Add conditional call for non-development environments for debug build. For example:

  ```cs
  if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
  {
      // ...
  }
  else
  {
  #if DEBUG
      app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
  #endif
      // ...
  }
  ```

Also check the [ASP.NET Core upgrade guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#blazor), was not able to find something there but maybe you will.

Comment: Perfect! that totally makes sense now - thanks for your help dude :)